# MYSQL retrieve featured image and post title

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I would like to retrieve a thumbnail version of the "featured image" 
this is the code I have but it is pulling the large image.

```
SELECT a.post_title title, max(c.guid) img_url, a.ID id, a.post_name
FROM wp_posts a    
LEFT JOIN
    (select post_parent, max(post_date_gmt) as latest_image_date
     from wp_posts
     where post_type='attachment'
     GROUP BY post_parent) b 
         on a.id=b.post_parent    
LEFT JOIN
    wp_posts c
    on c.post_parent=a.id 
     and c.post_type='attachment' 
     and b.latest_image_date = c.post_date_gmt
WHERE c.guid IS NOT NULL    
GROUP BY a.post_title
ORDER BY a.ID
```

Comment: Why are you doing this via your own SQL query, instead of using the methods WP already provides for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this query works for U. It's working absolutely fine for me.

```
SELECT p1.*, wm2.meta_value 
FROM wp_posts p1 
LEFT JOIN
    wp_postmeta wm1 ON (
        wm1.post_id = p1.id
        AND wm1.meta_value IS NOT NULL
        AND wm1.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
    )
LEFT JOIN
    wp_postmeta wm2 ON (
        wm1.meta_value = wm2.post_id
        AND wm2.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
        AND wm2.meta_value IS NOT NULL
    )
LEFT JOIN
    wp_term_relationships wtr ON (
        object_id=p1.id
    )
WHERE
    p1.post_status='publish'
    AND p1.post_type='post'
    AND `term_taxonomy_id`=?
ORDER BY p1.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```